# Including a php file from a parent directory

Tags: php

I have a user_ip_location.php file in "/user/files/new" folder.

full url to the file is

```
/user/files/new/user_ip_location.php
```

I want to include this file to **profile.php** file that is located in Root dir

I have tried the following code

```
 include("/././user_ip_location");
```

and

```
 include("http://example.com/user/files/new/user_ip_location");
```

Both are not working,  first is returning **no such file or directory** and the second  is not loading the page and the browser is returning error **could not locate to remote server**

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: which is your root directory??

Comment: I can make this suggestion but it won't make sense. Still, 1) Define a constant for your 'root directory' - I call mine: `APP_HOME_ROOT`. Then every directory I access is based on this. I never use a 'relative path' to access anything. Except it one circumstance - the 'application bootstrap' file as expect this to setup 'APP_HOME_ROOT'.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you are in `some` directory and want to include a file from `/user/files/new/user_ip_location.php`. So just including it by specifying the path should do the trick.

In your example this would be:
`include("/user/files/new/user_ip_location.php");`

If the file you want to include is levels above your current directory just specify this by using `..` like `include("../../user_ip_location.php");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
include './files/new/user_ip_location.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to indicate previous directory by double dots `..`

```
include("../../user_ip_location.php");
```